# Move a lambda expression to a static extension method in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

I am trying to refactor the following line of an Entity Framework query into a generalized static extension method:

```
dbContext.Employees
         .Where(e => permissionResolver.AuthorizedUsers.Select(p => p.Id).Contains(e.Id))
         .OrderBy(...)
```

`PermissionResolver` is just an instance I receive a list of IDs from to compare against a user ID stored in the current record. It compiles perfectly to a SQL statement `WHERE Id IN (....)`.

Now I am trying to create an extension method for `IQueryable<T>` that I can use for any type of record, I just want to pass in a property where the owner's ID is stored in.

So that is what I came up with:

```
public static IQueryable<T> AuthorizedRecords<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, Int32>> property, IPermissionResolver permissionResolver)
{
    Expression<Func<T, Boolean>> idIsAuthorized = entity => permissionResolver.AuthorizedUsers.Select(e => e.Id).ToList().Contains(property.Compile()(entity));                

    return query.Where(idIsAuthorized);
}
```

I'm getting a runtime error that this expression cannot be translated into SQL.

How can I combine the property expression to the main query expression that it can be translated into SQL correctly? Is there a better way to rewrite the query expression?

Comment: What about using a plain old `Func<T, Int32>` for the `property` parameter instead of an `Expression`?

Comment: No success, the same exception is raised on runtime. Maybe there was a mistake on calling the function inside the expression. I used `... .Contains(property(entity))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`property.Compile()` converts the expression tree into a delegate, this delegate cannot be properly translated back to an expression tree/SQL.

You need to construct expression tree like that:

```
var ids = permissionResolver.AuthorizedUsers.Select(e => e.Id).ToList().AsEnumerable();
// method Enumerable.Contains<int>()
var methodContains = typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable).GetMethods()
    .Where(m => m.Name == "Contains" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
    .First()
    .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(int));

 var lambdaParam = property.Parameters.Single();
 var lambda = Expression.Lambda(
     Expression.Call(
         methodContains,
         Expression.Constant(ids), 
         property.Body),
     lambdaParam
 );
 var predicate = (Expression<Func<T, bool>>)lambda;
 return query.Where(predicate);
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is you cannot use custom extension methods in entity framework queries. Under the hood entity framework parses expression tree `Expression<Func<>>` into sql query. It seems kind of impossible to translate any possible extension method to sql so they support limited set of Linq methods to properly translate it. Some useful information about expression trees: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees.
Some refactoring you can do to simplify your query is to use `Any` method like this:

```
dbContext.Employees
    .Where(e => permissionResolver.AuthorizedUsers.Any(u => u.Id == e.Id))
    .OrderBy(...
```